# UIActivityIndicatorView during dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app I just implement a dispatch_async block that will grab images from a NSDictionary and then eventually when the image is ready, set it to a UITableViewCell UIImageView. What I want to do is make a UIActivityIndicatorAppear in the middle of the UITableViewCell's UIImageView while the dispatch_async is occurring.

This is my code for the dispatch_async block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^(void) {
        NSData *data = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
        UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        //we get the main thread because drawing must be done in the main thread always
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
            [cell.imageView setImage:cellImage];
        } );

    });
```

Anyway is this possible? And if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the progress indicator **before** your `dispatch_async` and remove or hide it your main queue block where you set the image.

Comment: I could but that would mean all of my UITableView cells would show it at once and hide it at once. I want EACH UITableViewCell to hide it when its image is set.

Comment: If they all show the image at once, there is maybe not even the need for the second thread. You can still use this pattern and show one central progress indicator.